# A poison for fairies & fairy-tale beings

Tags: biology, warfare, weapons

My dwarves are starting a war with other inhabitants of Fairy. They have gone to Earth to seek a weapon. They can't import any weapon with iron/ steel. They find toy water pistols and wish to load them up with poisoned water of some sort. I am thinking not to kill but to render inactive. Spray a mist that causes sleep?

My question is what poison would you suggest? And what else could it do?
Or can you think of another no-iron weapon that dwarves could use to send fairies to sleep?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! At the moment, I feel like this question is too broad - we can't possibly tell you what would be poisonous to your fairies because we don't know anything about their biology. Would they be harmed by the same substances as humans?

Comment: Welcome, Ing!If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) 
useful. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, all super answers. Where would the dwarves easily get Chalcanthite on Earth?

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen, questions are closed for many reasons, but most are of the form, "you need to do a better job asking your question."  Consequently, you are NOT doing the OP any favors by answering the question in comments, which is against SE policy.  Rather than promoting poor question practice, please help the OP understand how to improve his/her question.

Comment: "*Where would the dwarves easily get Chalcanthite on Earth?*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcanthite